# Bootstrap Style in javaFx application?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am creating a GUI with scene builder using netbeans and i want to styling my application like the bootstrap style (button , table , menu .. ) 
How can i do that ,
cordially.

Comment: i want to do it without using Web view so the solution in the other question don't help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this one https://github.com/aalmiray/bootstrapfx

This adds support for some of the Bootstrap styles for your JavaFX Controls.